# WSO2 Developer Studio on OSX 10.10.3 freezes on launch

Tags: wso2

OSX 10.10.3
Dev Studio 3.7.1 installed via complete download from wso2.com or adding working eclipse via marketplace.

Freezes when I try to run the program. The splash shows "loading workspace". When Eclipse runs just fine prior to adding dev studio from the marketplace

How do I get WSO2 working on OSX 10.10.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom,

WSO2 Developer Studio can be installed using any of the bellow options;

1. Downloading the full pack from WSO2 site
2. Download Eclipse from the site and install the P2 repo which is downloaded from WSO2 web site
3. Download WSO2 DevStudio from Eclipse marketplace

Out of these methods which method(s) did you use? I used method 1 and 2 and works fine for me.

Comment: #1 eclipse will not start at all and #3 takes a working eclipse and breaks it. I did not try #2.

Comment: There is an issue with DevStudio for #1.

Comment: There is an issue with DevStudio for #1. for that can you follow the steps bellow;  
    1. Go to  DevS_HOME/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS , There will be two files called eclipse eclipse.ini
    2. Provide execute permission to the eclipse file
    3. start eclipse (from there itself)
    4. Next time onwards you can use the default eclipse starter to start eclipse as usual.